# Do you have to create dummy variables for ordinal variables? Also getting error with conversion

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

For the dataset that I am working with, the categorical variables are ordinal, ranging from 1 to 5 for three columns. I am going to be feeding this into XGBoost.

Would I be okay to just run this command and skip creating dummy variables:

```
ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], dtype='category')
ser = ser.to_frame()
ser = ser.T
```

I would like to know conceptually, since the categorical data is ordinal, would simply converting that to type category be adequate for the model? I tried creating dummy variables but all the values become a 1.

As for the code now, it runs but this command returns: 'numpy.int64'.

```
type(ser[0][0])
```

Am I going about this correctly? Any help would be great!

Edit: updated code

Edit2: Normalizing the numerical data values. Is this logic correct?:

```
r = [1, 2, 3, 100 ,200]
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
r = preprocessing.scale(r)
r = pd.Series(r)
r = r.to_frame()
r = r.T
```

Edit3: [This is the dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/default+of+credit+card+clients#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting categorical variables as `dtype="category"` is not sufficient and won't work.

You need to convert categorical values to true categorical values with `pd.factorize()`, where each category is assigned a numerical label.

Let's say `df` is your pandas dataframe. Then in general you could use this boilerplate code:

```
df_numeric = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()

# factorize categoricals columnwise
for c in df_obj:
     df_obj[c] = pd.factorize(df_obj[c])[0]

# if you want to one hot encode then add this line:
df_obj = pd.get_dummies(df_obj, prefix_sep='_', drop_first = True)

# merge dataframes back to one dataframe
df_final = pd.concat([df_numeric, df_obj], axis=1)
```

Since your categorical variables already are factorized (as far as I understand), you can skip the factorization and just try one hot encoding.

See also [this post on stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228260/does-it-make-a-difference-to-run-xgboost-on-hot-encoded-variables-or-single-fact).

If you want to standardize/normalize your numerical data (not the categorical) use this function:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

def scale_data(data, scale="robust"):
    x = data.values     
    if scale == "minmax":
        scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
        x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
    elif scale == "standard":
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
        x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
    elif scale == "quantile":
        scaler = preprocessing.QuantileTransformer()
        x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)      
    elif scale == "robust":
        scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler()
        x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)  
    data = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns = data.columns) 
    return data

scaled_df = scale_data(df_numeric, "robust")
```

Putting it all together [for your dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/default+of+credit+card+clients#):

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_excel("default of credit card clients.xls", skiprows=1)

y = df['default payment next month'] #target variable
del df['default payment next month']

c = [2,3,4] # index of categorical data columns
r = list(range(0,24)) 
r = [x for x in r if x not in c] # get list of all other columns
df_cat = df.iloc[:, [2,3,4]].copy()
df_con = df.iloc[:, r].copy()

# factorize categorical data
for c in df_cat:
     df_cat[c] = pd.factorize(df_cat[c])[0]

# scale continuous data
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df_con)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns=df_con.columns)

df_final = pd.concat([df_cat, df_scaled], axis=1)

#reorder columns back to original order
cols = df.columns
df_final = df_final[cols]
```

To further improve the code, do the train/test split before normalization, `fit_transform()` on the training data and just `transform()` on the test data. Otherwise you will have a data leak.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please let me know if I am understanding this properly. You are splitting the dataframe up into two dataframes, one with continuous data and one with categorical data. For the categorical data, you are factorizing it. Then you are appending it to the numerical dataframe. I am normalizing the numerical data as well. How would I go about doing that? I will include this in the next edit.

Comment: @mahesh Exactly. I have added a function that you can use to normalize your data with different scikit-learn scalers.

Comment: Thank you I understand categorical portion. Coming to the normalization, can you possibly shed some light on to the logic of the code you provided?

Comment: Additionally, when running through all the code, I will be getting rows in this format: [numerical, cat, cat, cat, numerical, numerical.....]. There will only be three categorical variables in the entire row. Is there a way I can simply index which rows I want normalized and which specific rows I want to factorize? I would ideally want to avoid splitting them up.

Comment: It is simply a utility function that you can use. The default scaler is the RobustScaler, but you can use all the others as well by simple providing eg. «minmax» as the value for the scale argument. More information here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py

Comment: The first two lines of the boilerplate code do exactly what you are asking for. These lines split dtype «object» from the numerical data.

Comment: Okay I think that I understand you. So I can perform the normalization using any of the preprocessing and simply merge it back? And is the order in which they are merged the same every time (ex: index)?  Final question: the data that I want to use to predict with my model is exactly 1 row containing all features. I want to do the factorization, normalization and have to merged back in the exact same format as I train/tested with. Will the merge be in the same order index wise like when I merged in the past (will update test/train code to reflect this)?

Comment: I feel that if the order in which the merge changes (in respect to when I train/test and when I try and predict) it would have a negative impact on my models performance? Just wanted to ensure.

Comment: The code separates your data columnwise and doesn't change anything reg. the indexing of the rows.

Comment: You need to process **all** your data with this code beforehand. Then you split train/validation/test.

Comment: If you want to predict on new data you have to «keep» the instantiated scaler and just do a `transform()`and not a `fit_transform()`. Otherwise your new data is normalized differently and your models perfomance will degrade.

Comment: Right so I am wondering when I split it column wise and merge it back together, the merge will happen at the same point every time correct? And the second and third comment you just left makes perfect sense thank you!

Comment: I removed the `reset_index()` from the code to make sure your indexing is not changed.

Comment: The split/merge will leave the column order of your dataframe unchanged.

Comment: Hello, I am getting this error when running the code. Will update in edit: ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176591/discussion-between-petezurich-and-rmahesh).